# MySQL monitor prompt does not return for slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm trying to fix a replication error (or an ongoing failure to replicate) between our master and slave MySQL databases.

The procedure I have asks me to use MySQL Monitor to stop the slave.

```
stop slave;
```

When I try this, however, the prompt never returns. I've left it for several minutes before Ctrl+C'ing out.

Interestingly, the same thing occurs with:

```
show slave status;
```

...but

```
show master status;
```

Works fine. Is there some other way I can kill the slave process off, ideally without interrupting the master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this happens, I immediately go to the Slave and

#### If you have MySQL 5.1+

```
SELECT id FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user='system user';
```

This will show you the Process ID of the IO Thread and SQL Thread of Replication.

#### If you have MySQL 5.0

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

You would have look for the two rows in the display that has `'system user'` as the user.

#### Once you find the IDs...

You can run the [`KILL` or `KILL QUERY` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html) against the Process IDs.

#### CAVEAT

This is a possibility that evn the KILL command can hang if the query must come to a completion (such as a transaction that must fully commit or fully rollback).

Master is oblivious to all this.

#### Why does `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` work just fine ???

Running `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` simply checks for binary logs on the DB Server. There are no DB threads to read, parse, examine, and coalesce.

Running `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` has to reconcile three(3) aspects:

- Aspect #1 : the Contents of `master.info`
- Aspect #2 : the current list of relay logs
- Aspect #3 : information acquired from the IO and SQL threads (live)

This reconciliation helps produce the output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`. It's Aspect #3 that makes `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` freeze attempts to kill the SQL thread on a long running query.

Comment: +1 as always; to expand on one of your points, for future reference for those who may not find it intuitive: `SHOW MASTER STATUS` does *not* show the status of the master of the server where the command is executed -- it's not "show the status of my master" -- although that's a reasonable assumption.  Instead, it gives information about the binlogs being *created* on the *local* server where the statement is executed... so unless the slave is also a master to one or more downstream slaves, running this on a slave provides information that is not generally useful.